# Replace string in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I want to replace all the `"."` with `"-"` in my DataFrame.

For instance,

```
    Symbol  Company                 Sector
230 TRP     TransCanada Corporation Energy
231 TCL.A   Transcontinental Inc.   Industrials
```

to something like this

```
    Symbol  Company                 Sector
230 TRP     TransCanada Corporation Energy
231 TCL-A   Transcontinental Inc.   Industrials
```

I have tried a few method, but it doesn't seems to work, such as    `stock_frame['Symbol'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(".","-"))`

Thanks

Comment: Your code works for me if I modify it to:  `stock_frame['Symbol'] = stock_frame['Symbol'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(".","-"))`

Comment: @dagrha - I got this error: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'.
I think it apply the function to the index instead of the value.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the str method of the Symbol Series instead?

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 30 2014, 15:34:38) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> tickers = [('TRP', 'TransCanada Corporation', 'Energy'), ('TCL.A', 'Transcontinental Inc.', 'Industrials')]
>>> tickers
[('TRP', 'TransCanada Corporation', 'Energy'), ('TCL.A', 'Transcontinental Inc.', 'Industrials')]
>>> tickers_df = pd.DataFrame(tickers, columns=['Symbol', 'Company', 'Sector'])
>>> tickers_df
  Symbol                  Company       Sector
0    TRP  TransCanada Corporation       Energy
1  TCL.A    Transcontinental Inc.  Industrials
>>> tickers_df.Symbol= tickers_df.Symbol.str.replace('.','-')
>>> tickers_df
  Symbol                  Company       Sector
0    TRP  TransCanada Corporation       Energy
1  TCL-A    Transcontinental Inc.  Industrials
>>>
```

Comment: you da real mvp. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pandas' own [replace function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)..

Rebuilding your sample DataFrame:

```
stock_frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'Symbol': ['TRP', 'TCL.A'], 
    'Company': ['TransCanada Corporation', 'Transcontinental Inc.'], 
    'Sector': ['Energy', 'Industrials']})
```

Now run the replace command.

```
stock_frame['Symbol'].replace({"\.": "-"}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The result is exactly what you're looking for.

```
  Symbol  Company                 Sector
0 TRP     TransCanada Corporation Energy
1 TCL-A   Transcontinental Inc.   Industrials
```